# Why is one of my gallery images out of place?

Tags: html, css, implementation

Here's a link to my site (Currently a work in progress so very basic right now):

[website](http://www.googledrive.com/host/0B42VhxW3Gqg1VmMtZnpuZVhCTm8/)

I just can't figure out why one image is messed up. It's not even the last image in the gallery and it's the same size as all the other images. Maybe i'm missing the obvious, I'm pretty tired.

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/b0r684hh/2/

HTML

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <h1 class="page-header">Ryk Design</h1>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="col-lg-2 page-header">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a class="invert" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="invert" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>-->
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="photos">
      <ul id="photo-gallery">
        <li>
          <a href="img/DoomQuoteMed.png">
            <img src="img/thumbs/DoomQuoteThumb.png">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/crop/SlaveBlur.png">
            <img src="img/thumbs/SlaveBlur.png">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/love wins2.png">
            <img src="img/love wins2.png">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/rd.png">
            <img src="img/thumbs/rdcrop.png">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/crop/taplrCrop.png">
            <img src="img/thumbs/taplrCrop.png">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="img/cider.jpg">
            <img src="img/cider.jpg">
          </a>
        </li>
        <!--<li>
                    <a href="http://40.media.tumblr.com/7302cf024c924726c6ad99bb80b0be41/tumblr_nauccbKUCw1tubinno1_1280.jpg">
                        <img src="http://40.media.tumblr.com/7302cf024c924726c6ad99bb80b0be41/tumblr_nauccbKUCw1tubinno1_1280.jpg">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://41.media.tumblr.com/fddb3f2b0bdf390efd7ea87372e75fa5/tumblr_ndyg3pYbKW1tubinno1_1280.jpg">
                        <img src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/fddb3f2b0bdf390efd7ea87372e75fa5/tumblr_ndyg3pYbKW1tubinno1_1280.jpg">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://41.media.tumblr.com/758a5cb9046fde53138ad0f55527ca25/tumblr_ndyfdoR6Wp1tubinno1_1280.jpg">
                        <img src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/758a5cb9046fde53138ad0f55527ca25/tumblr_ndyfdoR6Wp1tubinno1_1280.jpg">
                    </a>
                </li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
a,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
  font-size: 92px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

.invert {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.col-md-4 p {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav,
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page-header {
  border: none;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

footer {
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.row {
  padding-left: 0;
}

#photos {
  opacity: .88;
}

#photos img {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 1px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#overlay img {
  margin: 10% auto 0;
  width: 550px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#photos {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#photo-gallery {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Cheers for the help guys!

Comment: Please clarify the problem.  I don't see anything wrong with it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6dAWA.png

Comment: Relative image paths will not work outside of your website. Please update your fiddle.

Comment: My bad. The website link was meant to go to my test site not the live one. Updated the link. I change the fiddle too.

Comment: Okay updated the fiddle too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should float li elements instead of img elements, just change the css,

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0r684hh/4/)

```
#photos li {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 1px;
}

#photos img {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Legend. All fixed and thank you! I will make sure to do that from now on :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the first image having a bigger height than the others. If you inspect your images, you'll see that all of them have a height of 339px - EXCEPT the first image - that one is 339.33.

Since you are floating your images, this very slight difference throws off the alignment. There 2 solutions:

1) Set all of the images the same height

2) Clear the first image of each row so it resets the alignment. So with your example, having 3 images across you would want to clear the 4th image:

```
#photo-gallery li:nth-child(3n+1) img {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: I wrote a detailed blog post on this problem with sample code and screenshots if you're interested in digging a bit deeper: http://uxmilkshake.com/using-nth-child-to-align-your-floating-div-elements/

Answer (score 0):

its seems the first image height is .39 bigger so pushes them around.  But you should be able to do this better etc

something like this might help as well.
http://codepen.io/simondavies/pen/VaRBMo

```
   <div class="image-outer-wrapper">
     <div class="image-wrapper CasinoLink"></div>
     <div class="image-wrapper CorpLink"></div>
     <div class="image-wrapper CasinoLink"></div>
     <div class="image-wrapper CorpLink"></div>
     <div class="image-wrapper CasinoLink"></div>
     <div class="image-wrapper CorpLink"></div>
   </div>



   .image-outer-wrapper {
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     position: relative;
   }
   .image-outer-wrapper:before,
   .image-outer-wrapper:after { content: " "; display: table;}
   .image-outer-wrapper:after {clear: both;}

     .image-outer-wrapper .image-wrapper {
       margin:5px;
       position: relative;
              float: left;
       width: 279px;
       height: 237px;
       text-decoration: none;
       transition: background-position 500ms;
       cursor: pointer;
   }

     .image-outer-wrapper .image-wrapper.CasinoLink {
       background: url('http://placehold.it/558x237');
       background-position: 0 0;
     }
     .image-outer-wrapper .image-wrapper.CorpLink {
       background: url('http://placehold.it/558x237');
       background-position: 0 0;
     }

     .image-outer-wrapper .image-wrapper:hover {
       background-position: -279px 0;
   }
```